# Ignorar verificação de tipo de dados ao usar $.inArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Estou tendo o seguinte problema com o `jQuery`: Quando tento verificar um valor existente dentro de um array, com o método `$.inArray`,  ele está retornando um resultado inesperado.

Exemplo:
Quero verificar se `1232` existe dentro do `Array`, que é retornado por pela função `$.map`. Da seguinte forma:

HTML

```
<div class="elemento" data-nome="teste"></div>
<div class="elemento" data-nome="1232"></div>
```

Trecho do código jQuery

```
var value = $('.input').val();

var definedNames = $('.pai').find('.elemento').map(function(){

    return $(this).data('nome');

}).toArray();

if ($.inArray(value, definedNames) !== -1 || !value.length) {

    return false;
}
```

O que está ocorrendo é que dentro do `map`, o retorno de `data('nome')` (no caso do valor 1232) é do tipo `Number`; porém, quando vem do `$('.input').val()`, ele vem como `String`

No PHP há uma maneira de verificar pela função `in_array`, se os valores são também do mesmo tipo.

Exemplo:

```
in_array(1, ['1']) // true
in_array(1, ['1'], true) // false
```

No jQuery, existe alguma maneira de especificar que eu quero achar no array o mesmo valor, porém ignorando a verificação de tipo? Ou eu vou ter sempre que converter o número para `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que deve estar convertendo o valor de string para Number é o `.data`, que é uma função do jQuery que confunde um pouco as pessoas. Ela não foi feita simplesmente para ler/escrever valores dos *data-attributes*, e sim para se associar dados arbitrários a elementos do DOM (sem pendurá-los diretamente nos elementos, o jQuery cria um dicionário internamente).

Por isso, eu acredito que alterar a maneira como você cria a array já seria suficiente:

```
var definedNames = $('.pai').find('.elemento').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('data-nome');
}).toArray();
```

Isso vai montar uma array com o valor original do atributo `data-nome` de cada elemento, e valores de atributos são sempre strings.

Comment: muito bom! nem precisa da gambiarra do `toString()` rsrsrsrsrsrs

Comment: Qual `toString`?

Comment: O que eu ia colocar caso não encontrasse uma resposta. `return $(this).data('nome').toString()` dentro do `$.map`

Comment: Ah! Complementei a resposta agora explicando por que não precisa.

Comment: 3 minutos para marcar como resolvido :)