# Setar atributos "data - * " genéricos com javascript;

Tags: javascript, jquery, atributos

Eu preciso recuperar todos os meus atributos data, e setar as informações em um atributo data especifico.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="box_campo">
    <input type="text" data-valor="0">
    <ul>
        <li>apenas exemplo</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="box_campo">
    <input type="text" data-campo="0">
    <ul>
        <li>apenas exemplo</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script >
 $( document ).on( "click", ".box_campo ul li", function() {

    $(this).prev('input').attr('data-AQUI ESTA A DUVIDA', valor);

 });
</script>
```

como posso escrever a função para que ela possa alterar tanto o data-campo como o data-valor?

Desculpem mas realmente está difícil encontrar alguma referência;

Comment: Onde queres colocar o quê? podes dar um exemplo de qual `data-` deve ir para onde? queres colocar noutro HTML ou numa variável?

Comment: talvez isto ajude, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862423/regular-expression-in-data-attribute-jquery

Answer (score 2):

A função `jquery.data` não seta o atributo `data-` ele apenas faz o gravamento na "memória".

No caso você pode criar uma função usando `jQuery.fn.extend`, assim:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  "dataAttr": function(name, value) {
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return $(this).attr("data-" + name);
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-" + name, value);
    });
});

 $( document ).on( "click", ".box_campo ul li", function() {

    $(this).prev('input').dataAttr('ATRIBUTO', valor);

 });
```

> **Nota:** `jquery.data` trabalha com os atributos `data-`, conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50355/3635).

### Alternativa

Se você necessita apenas gravar os dados nos elemento e recupera-los apenas, você pode usar o [`jquery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), sem necessitar de atributos.

Exemplo de uso:

```
$(this).prev('input').data( "foo", 52 );
$(this).prev('input').data( "bar", { myType: "test", count: 40 });
$(this).prev('input').data( { baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] });
$(this).prev('input').data( "foo" ); // 52
```

Seu código deve ser algo como:

```
 $( document ).on( "click", ".box_campo ul li", function() {
    $(this).prev('input').data('Sua chave', valor);
 });
```

Pra testar:

```
 $( document ).on( "click", ".box_campo ul li", function() {
    alert( $(this).prev('input').data('teste') );//Retorna undefined

    $(this).prev('input').data('teste', 'valor');

    alert( $(this).prev('input').data('teste') );//Retorna valor

    alert( $(this).prev('input').attr('data-teste') );//Provavelmente retorna undefined
 });
```

Comment: Nunca consegui alterar o valor um `data-attribute` usando `.data()`, sempre tive que usar `.attr()`.

Comment: @KaduAmaral e não é que você tem razão, ao menos no jquery do SOpt não funcionou (fiz o teste pelo console) - jquery 1.7.1 -- aparentemente não tem nada haver diretamente com o atributo `data-`

Comment: @KaduAmaral O `data` do jQuery não manipula atributos, e sim propriedades de um objeto (interno). Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50042

Comment: Aliás, eu expliquei direito foi nesta outra aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50355

Answer (score 2):

Existem dois problemas no teu código.

Um deles é a dúvida que tens sobre como se usar o jQuery para pegar/escrever no `data-`.    O outro problema é talvez a razão de não teres conseguido o resultado quando testas-te com o `data-`.

O teu HTML é

```
<div class="box_campo">
    <input type="text" data-campo="0">
    <ul>
        <li>apenas exemplo</li>
```

e juntaste um oscultador de evento para o `li`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".box_campo ul li", function() {
```

E dentro do oscultador de evento estás a usar o `$(this).prev()`.
Um dos problemas está exatamente aqui. O [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) seleciona siblings, elementos do DOM que estão no mesmo nível e não ancestrais. No caso do teu `input` tens mesmo de combinar o [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) e o [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Para "encontrares" esse input a partir do `$(this)` precisas:

```
$(this).closest('.box_campo').find('input')
```

aí já podes setar o `data-` ou o `value`. [Ainda não sei bem o que queres fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74468/setar-atributos-data-gen%C3%A9ricos-com-javascript#comment152140_74468) mas se queres setar ou ler o `data-` podes usar

```
.data('nomedocampo', 'valor a atribuir'); // escrever no elemento
.data('nomedocampo'); // só para ler
```

Se quiseres setar ou ler o `value`/valor do input:

```
.val('valor a setar'); // escrever no value do elemento
.val(); // só para ler
```

Comment: Só não esqueça que [o `data` às vezes não faz o que parece](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50355), inclusive se o atributo tem hífen ele troca a chave pra camelCase.

Comment: @bfavaretto pois o `.data()` do jQuery é bem imprevisível às vezes. [esta outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3504/129) é uma boa referência, deixo aqui para o AP.

Answer (score 0):

Em jQuery para manipular o atributo `data-*` use assim:

Para pegar: `$('#campo').data('valor');`
Para setar: `$('#campo').data('valor', 8);`

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvi uma extensão para o jQuery que talvez ajude.

```
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.attrData = function(k, v){

        var attrs = jQuery(this[0].attributes);
        var attrsData = attrs.filter(function(index){
            return this.name.match(/^data/);
        });

        var len = attrsData.length;

        if(len > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                if(attrsData[i].name == 'data-'+k){
                    if(v == undefined){
                        return attrsData[i].value;
                    }else{
                        var data = attrsData[i].name; 
                        jQuery(this).attr(data, v);
                        return v;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            null;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(input).attrData('valor'); // 0
jQuery(input).attrData('valor', 1); // 1
```